# Does Allah send a person to hell if he is mad at them?

Tags: salat, halal-haram, hadith, allah, dua

This may sound like a stupid question but maybe that is because I am not smart when it comes to Islamic stuff.

In the hadith, it said that if one does not ask Allah: Allah gets angry.

But what is dua? My definition of dua is a wish.

Like wishing for a new car, new house etc.

Can you ask for a million cars in the Akhira or just wish for stuff in the dunya?
What does Allah do when angry? Will he punish the neglectful dua person by harddhips in the dunya or both in tge afterlife?

Or.... Allah punishes the person who did not ask by going to hell?

I feel troubled because I feel that I am greedy and selfish and nagging and annoying Allah.

So I simply asked for Paradise.

But... didn't the wife of the Pharoah asked for Jannag and was specific in dua by saying to Allah to have a palace next to him?

Because I am stuck in the middle.

If I dont ask and make duas-my definition of duas are wishes and if not correct me-and a the same time if I make duas id moght be considered specific.

If I simply ask for Jannah it makes me like the devil. Why the devil asked for only one wish didn't he?

Please help me and thanks

Comment: You're asking several things, can you specify which question you'd like answered?  The Hadith "He who doesn't ask Allah, he gets angry at him" is not authentic because one of the narrators -Abi Saaleh- is unreliable and it's reported ambiguously

Comment: Oh, Uh who is Abi Saaleh? Did he go to medina and studied it? Also, how come islamqa.com and other professional websites uses that hadith a lot?

Comment: Abi Saaleh lived around 800 years ago and he was one of the people who claimed this was a Prophetic saying.  But Abi Saaleh wasn't a trustworthy person nor was his memory good for him to be reliable.   If you search this website for 'science of hadith' or similar,  you can see how a Hadith is spoken about.  It's basically hearsay passed on from one person to the next.

Comment: Btw, you can make dua for anything halal and be specific.  If you pray 5 times, prayer in itself is dua.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overthinking it. The point is that Allah (SWT) wants us to ask Him. He doesn't want us to rely on our own strength or efforts, but to ask Him for everything.

As long as we are doing everything we should do as Muslims, there's nothing at all wrong with being specific with what we want. I've made many du‘as that were specific, and were answered.

A du‘a won't necessarily be answered in this life, but in the life to come. Du‘as are not always answered, but it might be that we are asking for something sinful, or it might be that the reward is stored up for the day of resurrection.

According to a hadith of the Prophet (صلى الله عليه وسلم):

“There is no Muslim who calls upon his Lord with a du‘a in which there is no sin or severing of family ties, but Allah will give him one of three things: Either He will answer his prayer quickly, or He will store (the reward for) it in the Hereafter, or He will divert an equivalent evil away from him.” They said: “We will say more dua.” He said: “Allah’s bounty is greater.” [Narrated by Ahmad, 10749; Al-Tirmidhi, 3573. Classed as Saheeh by Al-Albaani in Mishkaat Al-Masaabeeh, 2199]

It is said in the Quran (interpretation of the meaning):

But perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not. [Surah al-Baqarah, 2:216]

Therefore, you should trust that Allah (SWT) will always give you the best, even if it is not expected to you, or if it seems that you don't like it. Everything He gives us is a blessing.